# Помогите передать данные граббера в управляемый массив

Tags: php, массивы

Мне необходимо получить массив никнеймов.
Дело в том что все данные выводятся отлично , но при разделении строки на массив 
`$vivod = preg_split("/[?[][\w]{1,2}]/", $vivod);` получается бред просто выходит вместо каждого ника array array , мне нужно передать этот список в массив для дальнейшего граббинга по каждому из них... что то вроде `$length = count($vivod);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {` как правильно сделать что б не всё в строке шло как выдает мне, а каждое отдельно...

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$data = file_get_html('http://w2.dwar.ru/instance_stat.php?outside=1&instance_id=131374891&finish=0');
if($data->innertext!='' and count($data->find('a'))){
  foreach($data->find('a') as $a){
   $vivod = $a->plaintext;
   $vivod = $vivod . '';



   echo $vivod[1] . '';


  }

}

?>
```

При обычном граббинге , выходит список в никнеймов в одну строку ... вот таким образом

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$data = file_get_html('http://w2.dwar.ru/instance_stat.php?outside=1&instance_id=131374891&finish=0');
if($data->innertext!='' and count($data->find('a'))){
  foreach($data->find('a') as $a){
   $vivod = $a->plaintext;
   $vivod = $vivod . '';
   echo $vivod . '';
  }
 }

?>
```

Можно ли упростить такой граббинг ? что б или быстрее грузилось ну или хотя бы место не занимало столько ?

```
// КЛАН
  $clan = file_get_contents($url);
    if (strpos($clan, 'images/data/clans/')){

     $pos = strpos($clan, 'images/data/clans/');
    $clan = substr($clan, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($clan, '.gif" width="13" height="13" border="0" alt="" align="absmiddle">');
     $clan = substr($clan, 0, $pos);
     $clan = str_replace('images/data/clans/','', $clan);
      $sclan = $clan;
   } else {
    $sclan = '';
    }
                /* Выполняем запрос. Если нез клана не выводить его. */
  if ($sclan) {
  $clanicus = '<img src="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/data/clans/'.$sclan.'.gif" border="0" alt="" />';
} else {
  $clanicus = '';
}
```

Comment: Есть страница, что сграбить с нее пытаешься? Формулируй вопрос корректно. p.s добрый вечер :D

Comment: Добрый вечер ... )) получаю ответ с граббера вот таким вот образом `-CroCop- [4]dok3 (ФЭО-Прайм) [4]Бубльдубль (ФЭО-Прайм) [4]` пытаюсь сграбить никнеймы... в массиве что б каждый отдельно был ...  друг от друга)

Comment: Но если добавить `print $vivod.'<br />';` то вместо одного `'<br />'` где то два или три выходит , и за закрытием скобки `}` уже не выносится ничего ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение получения никнеймов

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://w2.dwar.ru/instance_stat.php?outside=1&instance_id=131374891&finish=0');
preg_match_all("'userToTag\(\'(.*?)\'\);'si", $content, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => -CroCop-
    [1] => dok3 (ФЭО-Прайм)
    [2] => Бубльдубль (ФЭО-Прайм)
    [3] => _-CeSaR-_ (ФЭО-Прайм)
    [4] => войпель (ФЭО-Прайм)
    [5] => hooliganka221
    [6] => --_КотоФей_--
    [7] => -Horing- (ФЭО-Прайм)
    [8] => yula2
    [9] => koln
    [10] => Хаватар
    [11] => Диэль
    [12] => Перс Персович
    [13] => OLEGBRAY
    [14] => _смертник11_ (ФЭО-Прайм)
    [15] => -Татьяна27-
    [16] => poayk777
    [17] => Alexandr_Victory
    [18] => Bloodomen
)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)) сейчас помучию код )))если что надеюсь поможете ))

Comment: А подскажите данные как передать теперь ? `$length = count($match[1]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
print $match[$i];
 }` так не получается)

Comment: куда передать? Просто вывести список?

Comment: `foreach ($match[1] as $nickname) echo $nickname.'<br>';`

Comment: Спасибо , но если указываю переменную 1 раз ... `foreach ($match[1] as $nickname)
$url = "http://w2.dwar.ru/user_info.php?nick=".$nickname . $ups;` после уже выводится всего 1 последний ник и всё ..  далее указываю `echo $nickname.'<br>';` и выходит просто Bloodomen последний

Comment: Всё всё всё) вроде понял ) спасибо оргомездное)

Comment: фигурные скобки добавь

Comment: Понял )) а во внутрь можно поставить граббер уровня , вот из этого кода `&lvl=10&tSrc` таким образом попробовал не получается) `preg_match_all("&lvl=(.*?)&tSrc", $lvlp, $lvl);`

Comment: query string не обязательно парсить регуляркой, можно воспользоваться функцией `parse_str` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php

Comment: На счет parse_str вообще пример не понял) так паряс со строки которую сами и вводят ) а можешь подсказать на счет упрощения кода )) я вот скинул , граблю так иконку клана )))

Comment: Извиняюсь за непонятные немного коммент , я в вопросе добавил в конце код, моего парсера клана )) может каким то образом можно его упростить .? а то очень долго страница грузится, секунд 40

Comment: Извините, я вот отдельный вопрос задал с полным текстом граббера, если можете подскажите пожалуйста, буду благодарен) [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513757/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE)