# Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать парсер, всё работает но очень долго..)

Tags: php, парсер, инспекция-кода

Доброй ночи )) Помогите пожалуйста с парсером, он загружается более 60 секунд, беда, может как то можно другими запросами, что то поменять, вот сам скрипт парсера:

```
<?php set_time_limit (90); ?>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
table.table1{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-style: normal;
    border-collapse:separate;
}
.table1 thead th{
    padding:15px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #568F23;
    border:1px solid #93CE37;
    border-bottom:3px solid #9ED929;
    background-color:#9DD929;
    background:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.02, rgb(123,192,67)),
        color-stop(0.51, rgb(139,198,66)),
        color-stop(0.87, rgb(158,217,41))
        );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        center bottom,
        rgb(123,192,67) 2%,
        rgb(139,198,66) 51%,
        rgb(158,217,41) 87%
        );
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
.table1 thead th:empty{
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
}
.table1 tfoot td{
    color: #9CD009;
    font-size:32px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #444;
}
.table1 tfoot th{
    color:#666;
}
.table1 tbody td{
    padding:2px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#DEF3CA;
    border: 2px solid #E7EFE0;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
    color:#666;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.table1 tbody span.check::before{
    content : url(./images/check0.png)
}
  </style>
   <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        body{
            font-family: Georgia, serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: normal;
            letter-spacing: normal;
            background: #f0f0f0;
        }
        #content{
            background-color:#fff;
            padding:40px;
        }
        #content h1{
            font-family:"Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;
            color:#1D81B6;
            font-weight:normal;
            font-style:normal;
            font-size:42px;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #aaa;
        }
        #content h2{
            font-family:"Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;
            font-size:34px;
            font-style:normal;
            background-color:#f0f0f0;
            margin:40px 0px 30px -40px;
            padding:0px 40px;
            clear:both;
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            color:#aaa;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
        }

    </style>

</head>
 <table class="table1">
          <tbody>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Расса</th>
    <th>Ху Ис ХУ?</th>

<th scope="col" abbr="Живой">Живой??</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Копает">Копает?</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Джахом">С Джахом?</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Бой">Бой?</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Благи">Благи</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Лив">Лив</th>


  </tr>
 </thead>


<?php

$content = file_get_contents('http://w2.dwar.ru/instance_stat.php?outside=1&instance_id=131444356&finish=0');
preg_match_all("'userToTag\(\'(.*?)\'\);'si", $content, $match);



function getPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
    $data_fin = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data_fin;
}
?>

<?php
foreach ($match[1] as $nickname){
$ups = "&noredir=9462fa1c293699b04eb15e8b8d84b9ba";
$url = "http://w2.dwar.ru/user_info.php?nick=".urlencode($nickname) . $ups;
$ssil = '<a href='.$url.'>'.$nickname.'</a>';
$page = getPage($url);

// УРОВЕНЬ
 $lvl = file_get_contents($url);
    $pos = strpos($lvl, '&lvl=');
     $lvl = substr($lvl, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($lvl, '&tSrc=images');
     $lvl = substr($lvl, 0, $pos);
     $lvl = str_replace('&lvl=','', $lvl);
//   УРОВЕНЬ
// ЗВАНИЕ
 $zvanie = file_get_contents($url);
    $pos = strpos($zvanie, '/images/ranks/');
     $zvanie = substr($zvanie, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($zvanie, '.gif" width="13" height="13" border="0" alt="" align="absmiddle">');
     $zvanie = substr($zvanie, 0, $pos);
     $zvanie = str_replace('/images/ranks/','', $zvanie);
 // ЗВАНИЕ
 // КЛАН
  $clan = file_get_contents($url);
    if (strpos($clan, 'images/data/clans/')){

     $pos = strpos($clan, 'images/data/clans/');
    $clan = substr($clan, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($clan, '.gif" width="13" height="13" border="0" alt="" align="absmiddle">');
     $clan = substr($clan, 0, $pos);
     $clan = str_replace('images/data/clans/','', $clan);
      $sclan = $clan;
   } else {
    $sclan = '';
    }
                /* Выполняем запрос. Если нез клана не выводить его. */
  if ($sclan) {
  $clanicus = '<img src="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/data/clans/'.$sclan.'.gif" border="0" alt="" />';
} else {
  $clanicus = '';
}


      // КЛАН
        /* Выполняем запрос. Если у персонажа нет звания, либо скрыт ничего не выводить. */
   if ($zvanie) {
  $zvann = '<img src="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/ranks/'.$zvanie.'.gif" border="0" alt="" />';
} else {
  $zvann = '';
}

// ЖИВОЙ или ТРУП
 $trup = file_get_contents($url);
    $pos = strpos($trup, '&ghost=');
     $trup = substr($trup, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($trup, 'LC_id=');
     $trup = substr($trup, 0, $pos);
     $trup = str_replace('&ghost=','', $trup);

 if ($trup == 0) {
  $trupcus = '<img src="./images/check0.png" border="0" alt="" />';
} else {
  $trupcus = '<img src="./images/Red_x.png" border="0" alt="" />';
}
 //   ЖИВОЙ или ТРУП

// КОПАЕТ&nbsp;ИЛИ&nbsp;НЕТ
 $kopalk = file_get_contents($url);
    $pos = strpos($kopalk, '&farming=');
     $kopalk = substr($kopalk, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($kopalk, '&PkPath=');
     $kopalk = substr($kopalk, 0, $pos);
     $kopalk = str_replace('&farming=','', $kopalk);

 if ($kopalk == 1) {
  $kopal = '<img src="./images/check0.png" border="0" alt="" />';
} else {
  $kopal = '<img src="./images/Red_x.png" border="0" alt="" />';
}
 //   КОПАЕТ ИЛИ НЕТ

// Есть хаос или нет
 $haosin = file_get_contents($url);
    $pos = strpos($haosin, 'medalchaos_red');
     $haosin = substr($haosin, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($haosin, '.gif');
     $haosin = substr($haosin, 0, $pos);
     $haosin = str_replace('medalchaos_red','', $haosin);

  if ($haosin == '1311') {
  $haosina = '<img src="./images/check0.png" border="0" alt="" />';
} else {
  $haosina = '<img src="./images/Red_x.png" border="0" alt="" />';
}
// Есть хаос или нет

// идет бой или нет ?
 $fight = file_get_contents($url);
    $pos = strpos($fight, '&fightId=');
     $fight = substr($fight, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($fight, '&farming=');
     $fight = substr($fight, 0, $pos);
     $fight = str_replace('&fightId=','', $fight);

  if ($fight) {
  $fightres = '<a href="http://w2.dwar.ru/fight_info.php?fight_id='.$fight.'" target="_blank">В БОЮ</a>';
} else {
  $fightres = '<img src="./images/Red_x.png" border="0" alt="" />';
}
// конец боя
$blag = 'http://w2.dwar.ru/effect_info.php?nick='.urlencode($nickname);
$blagi = '<a href="'.$blag.'" target="_blank">Благи</a>';
$rass_mag = '<img src="./images/ico_magmar.gif" border="0" alt="" />';
$rass_hum = '<img src="./images/ico_human.gif" border="0" alt="" />';
  // Проверка покинул пещеры
 $metro = file_get_contents($url);
    $pos = strpos($metro, '&tLocation=');
     $metro = substr($metro, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($metro, '&tTitle=');
     $metro = substr($metro, 0, $pos);
     $metro = str_replace('&tLocation=','', $metro);
 if ($metro == '%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B') {
  $metrop = '';
} else {
  $metrop = '<img src="./images/Red_x.png" border="0" alt="" />';
}



// заканчиваем вывод благ
if (preg_match('/Магмары/',$page)) {

  ?>


  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $rass_mag ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $clanicus; ?> <?php echo $zvann; ?> <?php echo $nickname; ?> [<?php echo $lvl; ?>] <?php echo '<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/player_info.gif" border=0 width=10 height=10 align="absmiddle"></a>' ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $trupcus ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $kopal ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $haosina ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $fightres ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $blagi ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $metrop ?></td>

  </tr>


  <?php


    }

if (preg_match('/Люди/',$page)) {
  ?>


   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $rass_hum ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $clanicus; ?> <?php echo $zvann; ?> <?php echo $nickname; ?> [<?php echo $lvl; ?>] <?php echo '<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/player_info.gif" border=0 width=10 height=10 align="absmiddle"></a>' ?></th>
  <td><?php echo $trupcus ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $kopal ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $haosina ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $fightres ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $blagi ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $metrop ?></td>
  </tr>


  <?php



    }

}






?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: `file_get_contents($url);` в цикле достаточно вызвать 1 раз

Comment: Вот тут ошибка или новые правила русского языка? `/* Выполняем запрос. Если нез клана не выводить его. */`

Comment: да то по ночухе печатал так для себя)) глаза закрывались , спать хотелось ) я понял на счет `file_get_contents($url);` )) сейчас поубираю)

Comment: Правильно ли я сделал ? я `$get = file_get_contents($url);` и далее заменил везде запрос на `$lvl = $get; ,$zvanie = $get;` и т.д

Comment: Спасибо ))) загружается очень даже быстро в сравнении с предыдущим вариантом, 11-13 секунд и есть ответ)

Comment: А можно как то сделать , если ссылки нет на парсинг , что б выводило не `Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in W:\home\2.ru\www\11.php on line 144` а ошибку мою , заданную

Comment: Как вариант перейти на `curl` и использовать многопоточность используя `curl_multi_*` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php